# Microsoft Edge browser thumbnail tab opens by default instead of miniature tab

Tags: internet-explorer, website, microsoft-edge, default-settings, thumbnails

Whenever I open Microsoft Edge browser, I get a huge thumbnail in the header of the Windows window.  Why does this happen when I open by default?  How can I prevent this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

click the up arrow next to the "+".

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/edge_other-edge_win10/edge-browser-header-to-big/e0ef065e-2552-4c4a-af19-f5c013b7ee78